# How to add a big string with a underlined string in a NVARCHAR Column in SQL server

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, sql-server-2008-r2

I am building a crystal report which fetched a particular string from a NVARCHAR column in the database and display it.

i have got a big string which has a underlined string within, but when i copy paste the string from MS word to SQL the underline is dissappering.

Is there a way of storing a text with a underlined string in a NVARCHAR column.

Thanks

Comment: No, there is no fonts with underlines. So you can't use a nvarchar.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk thanks, but is there a way of writing a formula for the string to underline it

Comment: Maybe you can use a nvarchar and write html code. That would work in some situations. I imagine that could help you

Comment: Why is this question in Crystal reports though?

Comment: because i am trying to print a string with underline on a crystal report